# Automated tests with pyautogui by image recognition, the system no longer recognizes the print after a new deployment

Tags: python, pytest, pyautogui

I do automated tests with pyautogui by image recognition (prints), but every time there is a new deploy, the system no longer allows prints and I have to capture them again. Any solution?

I tried to reduce the threshold:

```
def _find_element(self, reference_image_path: str, threshold=0.5,
                      timeout=Config.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT) -> tuple:
        """
        Find an element on the screen using image recognition and return its coordinates.

        Args:
            reference_image_path (str): The path to the reference image to search for.
            threshold (float, optional): The confidence threshold for image recognition.
                Defaults to 0.8.
            timeout (int, optional): The maximum time (in seconds) to search for the element.
                Defaults to Config.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT.

        Returns:
            tuple: A tuple containing the X and Y coordinates of the found element.
        """
        start_time = time.time()

        while time.time() - start_time < timeout:
            try:
                coordinates = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(
                    reference_image_path, confidence=threshold)

                x, y = pyautogui.center(coordinates)
                return x, y
            except:
                pass #TODO

        pytest.fail(
            f"Unable to locate element {reference_image_path} after {timeout} seconds")
```

Comment: Without knowing what sort of reference image and how the screen looks like - really hard to say anything but i'd assume that the reference images are way too big - eg, they might have something else except the exact component.. Also, i'd log the actual exception and maybe even do a screenshot from the time where your _find_element() fails so that debugging the visuals could happen..

Comment: What do you mean by `prints`? Your code doesn't seem to include any print calls. What exactly do you mean by a "new deploy"? What actions are you you taking, exactly, to 'deploy' this?